# Mongo kafka connector, deserializer question

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka connect in order to read data from mongo and write them to kafka topic. I am using the mongo kafka source connector. The message coming to my listener throws following exception when i am trying to deserializer.

`(although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value`

why is the above error?

Answer (score 0):

my connectors had `org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter` instead of 
`org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter` This solved the problem.

Also in the spring when initializing the JsonDeserializer pass in the custom objectMapper for example like below

`objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);`
`objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());`

hope this helps someone